# Stability when taking power from Raspberry

Tags: power

[Disclaimer This is not a question about WOL]

I have a simple setup where I would like to use the Raspberry as a wake on lan unit. I use the Raspberry to stream the mac addresses of the relevant PC from a REST service using curl. Then I've written a small script using etherwake to send a magic WOL package to all the mac addresses I got from the service. The scripts runs as a service, so when the raspberry starts the magic takes off.

The idea is that the raspberry is turned on and off with the light, so when the light goes on the PCs starts, and when the light goes off the PCs turn off correct. This is achieved with a simple ping function to the Raspberry, when it misses 10 ping request the PC turns off.

So my question(s) is:

- How stable is the Raspberry, when I take the power each day?
- Is there something I should be aware of?
- What about writing/reading to the sd-card, can it malfunction?

The system is reliable that the Raspberry starts, or else the WOL packages are not send :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable Wake On LAN?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-i-enable-wake-on-lan)

Comment: I am not asking about WOL - please read before commenting :) I am asking about the Pis stability when I take the power from it every day. The WOL is a description of my setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "take the power from it" you mean simply disconnecting power without shutting down, you do run the risk of corrupting the SD card. Ideally, you should do an orderly shutdown before removing power. This will require something more than a simple on/off switch with the light.

Comment: Yes exactly! The ideal is to shut it down nice, but do you have any experiences with just taking the power?

Comment: @DNRN you can minimise the risk of damage by making as few writes to the SD card as possible, preferably none.

Comment: Bobstro is correct; although pulling the plug is not a guarantee of problems, there's a right way and a wrong way.  If you are saying, "I really want to do this the wrong way because the right way involves too much effort, is that okay?", then that's your question to answer.  Just do it.  Presumably no one is going to die or suffer because of this.   If the pi isn't doing much, chances are *it will usually be fine.*   I believe there may be an unpredictable element with the pi hardware itself, because some people seem to have much more problems with this than others.