# What distro is Wake on LAN capable the RapsBerry Pi 2?

Tags: networking

From my RapsBerry Pi 2 B running **Ubuntu 14.04LTS** I do:

```
sudo poweroff
```

So the device **turns off** (nothing on the screen).
If I then try to wake on LAN it up with the usual method:

```
wakeonlan 11:22:33:44:55:66
```

... nothing happens.
Any other desktop computer on my **LAN awakes fine**, so I must suppose this is some issue with the drivers.

The eth0 info in the RapsBerry seems **correctly configured** for wake on LAN:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Note the `Wake-on: g` part.

As long as the LAN card seems to be [Wake on LAN capable](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1432/29518), I assume that maybe another distro would be more optimized in ethernet drivers matter and could put the device in wake on LAN state?

For those arguing [there is no need](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-i-enable-wake-on-lan)(?) to wake on LAN the RapsBerry Pi, consider these scenarios:

- You have a Rapsberry that you would like to **go unnoticed** (hidden, nobody must know it is there; they could grab it, you know). So you let it off and you start it up (wake on LAN) when desired (only you will know the MAC address).
- You would like to fully stop the network to **isolate network traffic** in order to sniff LAN data and detect some misbehavior, failure, virus... etc. Going through all the computers/portables/devices to turn them all off is rather awkward. So you order some sort of `poweroff` (even massive poweroff by using some .sh script) and, later, you turn them all on again via Wake on LAN (massive method is possible to, for example with `wakeonlan` tool from Linux).

Answer (score 1):

As debated [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=95640), if the ethernet card is seen by the RapsBerry as connected via USB (even when it is on board), this should **not be possible for now**, whatever *your distro* is.

I have a modern RapsBerry Pi2 B (bought April 2015) and this is, indeed, the case:

```
luis@Zarzamoro:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:0002 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As for now (May 2015) we will **have to wait** for the developers to enhance this part of the RapsBerry.

Comment: Wake-on-LAN will not work on the current Pi's  You'll have to wait for a new model of Pi to come out which doesn't use USB Ethernet.

Comment: This was discussed in some detail on the [Raspberry Pi forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=103999&p=769719&hilit=wake+on+lan#p769719)